# How to add/ignore a subfolder in htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I have build an app at `http://url/sdf19/`

I have a .htaccess placed in /sdf19/ containing RewriteRule for clean urls.

But I have built a PDF generating tool, which is in a subfolder `/inc/tools`.
I need to link to it direct to run before headers.

Despite a few hours of searching, trying snippets, generators, etc. I cannot get any request to `http://url/sdf19/inc/tools` to be allowed, without the existing RewriteRule set taking over

Here is my starting file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC]
```

**THINGS TRIED:**

I've tried to add this on line 4;
`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ inc/tools/ [NC]`
This gave RewriteCond: bad argument line error

I've tried to add this to line 2;

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/inc/tools/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
```

I've tried adding a .htaccess in `/inc/tools` with RewriteEngine OFF, didnt work.

I'e tried the .htaccess tester linked on the top post, but whislt my file (above) works IRL, it produces 'rule not met' for everything on there!

**TL;DR**

Desired result is that I can allow direct access to `http://url/sdf19/inc/tools` > everything I have tried so far i get redirected to base `http://url/sdf19/`

Comment: My advice is to use **positive lookahead** (not tested)

Something like this

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^(?=(\/inc\/tools\/(.*)$)) 
 
 RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
`
I guess you should dig that way. Good Luck!

Comment: " i get redirected to base `http://url/sdf19/`" - Are you saying you are a seeing an _external redirect_ to `http://url/sdf19/`? If so, then "something else" would seem to be doing that?

Comment: "I'e tried the .htaccess tester linked on the top post" - What `.htaccess` tester? What top post?

Comment: "Here is my starting file" - do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 2):

A bit of discussion about your current rules...

> I've tried to add this on line 4; `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^ inc/tools/ [NC]` This gave RewriteCond: bad argument line error

Because you have an erroneous *space* in the middle of the *CondPattern* `!^ inc/tools/`. However, that expression still won't give the correct result (see below).

> I've tried to add this to line 2;
>
> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/inc/tools/(.*)$
> RewriteRule ^.*$ - [L]
> ```

You are close with this. However, the `REQUEST_URI` server variable contains the full URL-path, not the URL-path relative to where the `.htaccess` file is located. So, this would need to be of the form:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sdf19/inc/tools/
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

This would need to go near the top of your `.htaccess` file, immediately after the `RewriteEngine On` directive. The `(.*)$` at the end of the *CondPattern* was superfluous, as was the `RewriteRule` *pattern* `^.*$`. However, this can be written more efficiently as a single directive and testing with the `RewriteRule` *pattern* instead. You can then omit the `/sdf19` subdirectory. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^inc/tools/ - [L]
```

> I've tried adding a `.htaccess` in `/inc/tool`s with `RewriteEngine OFF`, didn't work.

Well, that *should* have worked. (Unless perhaps you have mod_alias directives in the parent `.htaccess` file that are conflicting?) So, it's unclear, given what you've stated in the question why it didn't. Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

> everything I have tried so far i get redirected to base `http://url/sdf19/`

That is also strange, because nothing you've shown so far would result in an external redirect. Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? A mod_alias `Redirect` or `RedirectMatch` directive perhaps?

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
> RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC]
> RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [NC]
> RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC]
> ```

A *potential* problem with these directives is that `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the *first* `RewriteRule` that follows. So, the 2nd, 3rd and 4th `RewriteRule` directives above are being executed unconditionally and explains why requests to `/sdf19/inc/tools` are being caught by the *third* rule.

You would either need to include those same conditions before *every* `RewriteRule` (ie. the rule is only processed when the request does not map to a file and does not map to a directory). Or, negate their meaning and prevent further processing if a file or directory is requested - however, this can depend on whether you have more directives later in your file that still need to be processed under these conditions.

You are also missing `L` flags on these directives, so processing is (unnecessarily?) continuing through your file.

So, try the following instead:

```
# Prevent further processing if a file or directory is requested
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
 
# Route other URLs
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/([a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)\/?$ index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding "RewriteEngine On" in your configuration file?

```
run_rewritemap_programs(server_rec *s , apr_pool_t *p){
if (conf->state == ENGINE_DISABLED) { // usage of "RewriteEngine"
  return APR_SUCCESS; // early return
rewritemap_program(...); // usage of "RewriteRule" 
}
```

Since the configuration default of "RewriteEngine" is "Off", from the code snippet above, "RewriteRule" is enabled only if "RewriteEngine On" is explicitly stated in the configuration file.

Another thing that is worth mentioning is the configuration default of "RewriteEngine" is "Off", so setting "RewriteEngine Off" itself is a silent misconfiguration error because it will not influence any system behavior.